# SNMP++ library ignore USM model and accept every input even without auth

Tags: c++, snmp, snmp-trap

I am building a C++ application which purpose is, among other thing, to receive SNMP traps. For this I am using SNMP ++ library version V3.3 (https://agentpp.com/download.html C++ APIs SNMP++ 3.4.9).

I was expecting for traps using no authentication to be discarded/dropped if configuration was requesting some form of authentication but it does not seem to be the case.

To confirm this behavior I used the provided receive_trap example available in the consoleExamples directory. I commented every call to

```
usm->add_usm_user(...)
```

except for the one with "MD5" as security name :

```
usm->add_usm_user("MD5",
            SNMP_AUTHPROTOCOL_HMACMD5, SNMP_PRIVPROTOCOL_NONE,
            "MD5UserAuthPassword", "");
```

I then sent a trap (matching the "MD5" security name) to the application using net-snmp :

```
snmptrap -v 3 -e 0x090807060504030200 -u MD5 -Z 1,1 -l noAuthNoPriv localhost:10162 '' 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1 i 123456
```

Since the application only registered User Security Model requires an MD5 password I would have though the trap would have been refused/dropped/discarded, but it was not :

```
Trying to register for traps on port 10162.
Waiting for traps/informs...
press return to stop
reason: -7
msg: SNMP++: Received SNMP Notification (trap or inform)
from: 127.0.0.1/45338
ID:  1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.0.1
Type:167
Oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.3.2.1
Val: 123456
```

To make sure there was no "default" UserSecurityModel used instead I then commented the remaining

```
usm->add_usm_user("MD5",
            SNMP_AUTHPROTOCOL_HMACMD5, SNMP_PRIVPROTOCOL_NONE,
            "MD5UserAuthPassword", "");
```

and sent my trap again using the same command. This time nothing happened :

```
Trying to register for traps on port 10162.
Waiting for traps/informs...
press return to stop
```

V3 is around 18k lines of RFC so it is completely possible I missed or misunderstood something but I would expect to be able to specify which security level I am expecting and drop everything which does not match. What am I missing ?

**EDIT Additional testing with SNMPD**

I have done some test with SNMPD and I somehow still get similar result.

I have created a user :

```
net-snmp-create-v3-user -ro -A STrP@SSWRD -a SHA -X STr0ngP@SSWRD -x AES snmpadmin
```

Then I am trying with **authPriv key :**

```
snmpwalk -v3 -a SHA -A STrP@SSWRD -x AES -X STr0ngP@SSWRD -l authPriv -u snmpadmin localhost
```

The request is accepted

**with authNoPriv** :

```
snmpwalk -v3 -a SHA -A STrP@SSWRD -x AES -l AuthNoPriv -u snmpadmin localhost
```

The request is accepted

**with noAuthNoPriv** :

```
snmpwalk -v3 -a SHA -A STrP@SSWRD -x AES -X STr0ngP@SSWR2D -l noauthnoPriv -u snmpadmin localhost
```

The request is rejected.

As I understand the authNoPriv must be rejected, but is accepted, this is incorrect from what I have read in the RFC and the [cisco snmpv3 resume](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/snmp/configuration/xe-3se/5700/snmp-xe-3se-5700-book/nm-snmp-snmpv3.pdf)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular library, but I am quite familiar with the v3 specs. I think you are looking at the wrong layer to address this problem. I think you need to address the issue in the "access control" layer. The SNMP Wikipedia page has this to say: "VACM (View-based Access Control Model) determines whether a given principal [i.e. user] is allowed access to a particular MIB object to perform specific functions and operates at the PDU level."

Comment: I'm a little confused, I didn't understand the point of USM if it is totally ignored by the server. This means that anyone can publish by default and steal the publisher's identity.

Why bother to implement this ?

Comment: USM verifies that the sender of the message holds the right credentials for a particular user, and then tells the ACM "I received a message from this user, and it is legitimate at this security level." The ACM decides whether that security level is enough to access a particular piece of information. It appears that you have the ACM configured to accept noAuthNoPriv for incoming traps.

Comment: If you want to verify that the USM is working properly, you can try sending a message with a security level of authNoPriv or authPriv using invalid credentials and make sure that it is rejected

Comment: Ok, I understand the principle, thanks, I will check this when my colleague comes back to work (covid...). If you are right I will ask you to create an answer.

Comment: I think the library is broken, I have post on the official forum : https://forum.snmp.app/t/critical-security-validation-of-usm-is-invalid/791

Then edit this post when I have receved feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** I am not expert so take the following with a pinch of salt.

I cannot say for the library you are using but regarding the SNMP v3 flow:

In SNMPv3 exchanges, the USM is responsible for validation **only** on the **SNMP authoritative engine** side, the authoritative role depending of the kind of message.

- Agent authoritative for : GET / SET / TRAP
- Receiver authoritative for : INFORM

The RFC 3414 describes the reception of message in section 3.2 :

> 5. If the information about the user indicates that it does not
>    support the securityLevel requested by the caller, then the
>    usmStatsUnsupportedSecLevels counter is incremented and an error
>    indication (unsupportedSecurityLevel) together with the OID and value
>    of the incremented counter is returned to the calling module.
> 6. If the securityLevel specifies that the message is to be
>    authenticated, then the message is authenticated according to the
>    user’s authentication protocol. To do so a call is made to the
>    authentication module that implements the user’s authentication
>    protocol according to the abstract service primitive

So in the step 6, the securityLevel is the one from the message. This means the TRAP is accepted by the USM layer on the receiver side even if the authentication is not provided.

It is then the task of the user of the TRAP to decide if the message must be interpreted or not.